# Install Windows 7 from USB in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 16.04, usb, windows-7, gparted

I prepared a Windows 7 ISO file, bootable pendrive by using `DISKS`.

Here's my system configuration.

[image: Disk space allocation]

[image: GParted, Unable to resize this]

[image: dev/ ls sd*]

Currently Ubuntu is running on my system (only one OS)
When I am trying to install the Windows 7 using a penddrive, it is showing no device is found. But am able to view the pendrive data/details once I'm logged into the system.

Is this problem due to partition issues?

Please give some guidance/suggestions on how to install Windows 7.

Comment: It's too late. Apparently you already formatted your Windows partition as EXT4? With that your Windows is gone.

Comment: Please tell us what you *want to do* now! Do you want to install Windows 7, or Ubuntu or both? -- And what have you got? Do you suspect that something is destroyed? In that case, is there a backup?

Comment: @MichaelBay  Previously I had used windows 8, from win8 I moved to ubuntu16.04.  Now I want to install win7. I am not interested on dual boot. try to install totally wind7 in my machine.

Comment: @sudodus I took backup from by ubuntu, Now I want to install win 7...

Comment: Head to your Windows installation disk and start partitioning, and then follow the installer's instructions to install it.

Comment: Why "Ask Ubuntu" how to install Windows? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Cynplytholowazy How can I do partitioning? will you pls give some guidance...

Comment: @EODCraftStaff because currently I am using Ubuntu OS

Comment: If the USB install drive for Windows 7 is working, it can do the whole job for you, including partitioning.

Comment: Keep your EFI system partition. Reformat `/dev/sdb2` into NTFS partition. Delete your swap space, it will be useless in Windows.

Comment: From what I understood, your question is "How can I install Windows 7". The question is completely Off-Topic and you should head to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), ask your question again and be more specific on what you want to do.

Comment: @Cynplytholowazy I don't have `/dev/sdb2`. I edited question and added a pic with info of  `cd \dev`, `ls sd*`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's `/dev/sda2`.

Comment: @sudodus I had followed your steps mentioned in the [mkusb-nox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu) its worked for me. Could you please let me know, what to do next for installing OS

Comment: What happens, when you plug in the USB pendrive into the computer and reboot? Does it boot into the Windows installer? If yes, just follow the instructions, if no, please tell us what is happening instead.

Answer (score 1):

As I said on comments, the question is Off-Topic, but since you want help with `gparted`, which is a GNOME partition-editing application run on Linux, I guess I can help you a bit.

In order to make a new OS Installation, you need to keep the ***EFI System Partition*** and delete everything else: ***linux-swap*** and ***ext4 (Win7)***. Then, you should have EFI and unallocated space (NOT unformatted).

Unfortunately, I can't help you any further. Google is your best friend.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, But format option is not available in GParted tool.

Comment: You cannot format anything if you have these partitions mounted. You should try booting via LiveUSB/LiveCD in order to delete the partitions. Do you use a Live USB/CD?

Comment: Did you right-clicked on the `/dev/sda2` entry? It will show up Format option there.

Comment: @Cynplytholowazy No, it is not, format option as disabled.  `Resize`, `Unmount` and `Name Partition` options are available.

Comment: @Rao As I said, in order to delete the partitions, get yourself a Live USB/CD in order to delete them while they're unmounted.

Comment: @Rao Installing any OS entails knowing about partitioning and how to do it and the specific OS requirements. Also knowing about UEFI/Legacy is crucial. And so is knowing that installing an OS has **nothing** to do with what's installed already if anything. Provided you have a bootable installation media for Windows - and knowing that's the only OS you want to install - ... Windows installation/troubleshooting is completely OFF TOPIC. If you need help with Windows you can ask at [superuser.se] or ask someone competent to do the installation for you as you clearly aren't.

Comment: Either way please stop asking people to help with something OFF TOPIC here.

Comment: @Rao Unmount all your partitions first before doing other things.